# What to Unit Test in a piece of code that just returns a list from DB?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have this piece of code I wrote and is used on an endpoint. Basically, a `SearchCatalogItemRequest` is just an object that contains just a `string` which is then used to filter a search using EF Core 7.

```
public async Task<List<Drug>> SearchDrugs(SearchCatalogItemRequest search)
    {
        var drugs = _unitOfWork.DrugRepository.Get()
            .Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.SearchString.Trim().ToLower())).ToList();

        return drugs;
    }
```

I've done Unit Tests before, but it has been for more 'fleshy' pieces of codes; this one just returns a list from the database based on a filter. What could I test in this case? Currently no test cases come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **persistence unit test** is appropriate for this piece of code. The test can setup test data in the test database that contains multiple rows, some of which meet the search criteria. The test would invoke the method to retrieve rows and then assert that only the rows that should have been returned based on the search criteria are returned. The test would subsequently clean up the database in the dispose method. This last part is important, because you want the cleanup to occur even if the test fails or blows up.

You can setup few different test cases:

- Database contains multiple rows, no rows are returned
- Database contains multiple rows, some rows are returned
- Database contains multiple rows, all rows are returned
- Database contains no rows, no rows are returned